# Probability of 4 balls in the same jar

Tags: probability

I put 10 balls numbered 1 through 10 in a black box. Next to it, I placed two jars, labeled "A" for the first jar and label "B" for the second jar.

I want to distribute the balls in the jars as follows:

1- I take a ball randomly from the box and place it in the "A" jar.

2- I take a ball randomly from the box and put it in the "B" jar.

3- I take a ball randomly from the box and place it in the "A" jar.

...

I will perform these steps until all the balls are distributed in the jars as shown.

Question: What are the chances of balls 1,2,3 and 4 being in the same jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like each jar gets $5$ balls.  You want to know the probability that four desired balls end up in jar A or jar B.

Let's look at the probability ($p_\text{A}$) they end up in jar A.  We'll multiply by $2$ at the end.

There are $\pmatrix{10 \\5}$ ways of selecting $5$ balls and putting them in jar A.  How many have $\{1,2,3,4\}$?  Well, there are six other balls, so:

$$p_\text{A} = \frac{6}{\pmatrix{10 \\5}}=\frac{6\cdot5!\cdot5!}{10!}=\frac{ 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{10\cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 }=\frac{1}{42}$$.

The probability that all four balls $\{1,2,3,4\}$ end up in the same jar is thus:

$$p=2p_\text{A} = \frac{1}{21}.$$

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I was unable to think of this model. In my head I was relating something to inclusion-exclusion because of the alternating jar change.

Comment: You are welcome!